What does "boomerang" really mean?
Jakob and Little B were listening to music while driving:

Jakob: This guy was an underwear model.
Little B: What?
Jakob: Yeah. Oh, yeah. Here we go and... Little B, bring it back. It's
a boomerang. It's a boomerang, maybe.

Little B starts to dance with his neck to the song, along with Jakob.
What does "boomerang" really mean?

Means that the music is coming back at you and makes you wiggle?
